# sharepoint hosted app pages authorization

Tags: security, sharepoint-addin, security-trimming, authorization, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have multiple pages in a SharePoint 2013 hosted app. I need to restrict access to some of the pages to certain group. what is the best practice to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about doing this from code or from the SP UI?

Answer (score 0):

Permission levels is one of the beautifull feature of sharepoint which always keeps its charm alive :)

Well you can **always apply permissions on the individual pages**, There is a manage permissions option for each item(lists/pages/libraries/documents/etc). Here are the steps to do restrict access:

1.Open the permissions page for the pages you want to restrict access to, and break inheritance from its parent.

2.Remove groups or users that you don’t want to have access to the page

3.Grant permissions to new groups or individuals that you do want to have access.

hope this helps!

Comment: how to Open the permissions page for the "app pages" from office 365.